# blank input field message different under internet explorer v11

Tags: php, html

Something has puzzled me for few days now, how can i standardize input validation message in Internet explorer 11 and the code below works fine and the message is fine under chrome, firefox etc.

i have a field for email and i check it to make sure the email is in a specific way pattern matching this works fine and i have a submit button with the field. If this email field is empty it should display a message "please fill in field" under chrome,firefox but when i try it under I.E v11 this standard message is different , how can i force this message to be same in I.E V11..

```html
<form method="post" action="web url to a page"> 
    <p>
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       <input title="(Please enter your email address.)" required="required" name="email" type='email' pattern=".+(@hotmail.com)|.+(@gmail.co.uk)" required />
    </p>
    <input style="float: right;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Comment: hi there peehaa i get "this is a required field" under internet explorer 11 where as under chrome and firefox i get a same message "please fill out this field" and the message i have in my code in round brackets (Please enter your email address) which correct if there is nothing in the email field and you submit it blank , but i want to standardise this message under Internet explorer 11, is it possible !!..thanks in advance...singhy

Comment: How is the title attribute related to the error message?

Comment: hi there peehaa code does not have an error, all validations are correct, it is to standardize the message i get under Internet explorer 11, where as the other browsers give a same message output !, is there anyway of overriding the output message under I.E 11 if yes how can i achieve this, thanks in advance...

Comment: Perhaps you will have more luck with https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity?

Comment: thanks will have a go, but i thought this could be solved much more easily, has anyone else come across this !!, thanks again for your help...singhy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89529/discussion-between-user3723480-and-peehaa).

Comment: Add the "novalidate" attribute to the form, and make your own validation methods and messages. The built-in ones aren't that great anyway.

Comment: hi rjdown thanks for the response, starter code would be helpful thanks in advance... not too familiar with it yet, thanks

Comment: http://formvalidation.io/

Comment: thanks, checking out formvalidation.io link now !, thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

firstly thanks for all the help i got, below is the code i used to sort the issue i had with the I.E 11 message output, see below..thanks singhy

```js
function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['frm'].question.value == "")
  {
    alert("empty");
    return false;
  }
    return true;
}


<form name="frm">
  Question: <input name="question"/> <br />
  <input id="insert" onclick="return IsEmpty();" type="submit" value="Add Question"/>
</form>
```